# JavaScript Async await sequential is not working, it's not waiting on the response

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to write an async sequantial function, but it looks like the next line of code will not wait till the first one is done. The problem is inside 'loadContract' function. This is the full code:

```
import contract from "../assets/static/build/contracts/PolarBetV4.json";
let web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);

const contractABI = () => {
  const abi = contract.abi;
  return abi;
};

const startWeb3 = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    window.ethereum.enable();
  } else {
    window.alert("Metamask not detected!");
  }
};

const loadContract = async () => {
  try {
    const address = await web3.eth.ens.getAddress("polarbet.eth");
    console.log(address);

    const result = await new window.web3.eth.Contract(contractABI(),address);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

export const LoadWeb3 = async () => {
  await startWeb3();
  window.contract = await loadContract();
};
```

If I change 'address' to the string it should be, like:

```
    const result = await new window.web3.eth.Contract(contractABI(), '0xc980207f705242EaKasedkDb2b');
```

It works. I already checked the output of 'address' using the console log. And it's the same string. But it looks like it is not waiting on the response and this line is already triggered with the promise. So not sure how I can solve this?

Comment: Since this question doesn't pertain to react or web3 (though it's used, it's not the subject of the question), you should remove those  tags.

Comment: Thanks, just removed them

Comment: can you try chaining with `then` instead? like `web3.eth.ens.getAddress("polarbet.eth").then(address => new window.web3.eth.Contract(contractABI(),address)).then(console.log)`. At web3 repo people seem to have the same problem. In the docs they talk about `promiEvent` which may suggest that they dont return native JS promise, but a promise-like.

Comment: @buzatto same error unfortunately, I will check the repo as well

Comment: fwiw https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/2837 https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/10216

Comment: If web3 returns promise-like objects rather than native promises, as @buyatto suggested, you may be able to wrap the in a `new Promise` from [Bluebird.js](https://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/new-promise.html). It tends to handle converting non-native Promises well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `loadContract` function is asynchronous. Async functions always return a promise. In this case, the function returns a (pending) promise that eventually resolves to the value of your `result` variable.

This happens immediately and is the intended behaviour of async functions. If you're still unsure, I suggest you read up on them in [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

If you want your code to wait until `window.contract` is resolved, you should `await` your LoadWeb3 fn.

```
e.g.:

await LoadWeb3();

doSomethingWithTheContract(window.contract);
```

Comment: LoadWeb3 is called in my index.tsx file, before rendering the app (react app). Now I wrote: ```(async() => {await LoadWeb3()})();```, but I will receive the same error.